# wildcard 301 redirect to ignore variable in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Instead of writing a simple redirect for all my old product urls, I need a rewrite rule to redirect several links with very similar urls that are only different by one numeral that is separated by periods. The example below of the several links that will all redict to a single url. Also, the character case should be ignored as well in the 'a131.1.html' and i the destination url for the file name portion only.

```
site.com/product/cat/a131.1.html
site.com/product/cat/a131.2.html
site.com/product/cat/a131.3.html
site.com/product/cat/a131.4.html
...
site.com/product/cat/a131.30.html

to

new-site.com/101
```

Comment: Where does the "101" come from? For instance what "a131.3" should become?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that (as I don't clearly understand what should become what):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/cat/a([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.html$ http://new-site.com/$1-$2 [L]
```

(I haven't tried it, but hopefully it should work. In the worst case, you now have an idea of the route to follow, what you should look for)

Comment: product/cat/a131.1.html should become newsite.com/b321 and product/cat/a131.2.html should become newsite.com/b321 etc.

Comment: @user2278150 So the last part is ignored? And where does the 321 come from?

Comment: the a131.1.html and all like it is an old product url i want to redirect to new product url which is newsite.com/b321

Comment: Thank you. works now. I was able to solve it with the below using your original post and also looking at a standard redirect:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.cin$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
    RewriteRule ^pruducts\/cat/a131\.([0-9]+)\.html$   "http\:\/\/www\.newsite.com\.org\/B321" [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink your .htaccess a bit.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^product/cat/a131\.\d+\.html$ http://newsite.com/b321 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes, `\d` stands for all digits and I thought I could condense your two HOST conditions.